# Understanding the 'this' keyword for a prototype function of a object

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
var Controller = function () {

try {
    throw new this.userException('test', 'test');
  } catch (error) {
    if (error instanceof this.userException) {
      console.error(error.stack);
    }
  }
}


Controller.prototype.userException = function (name, message, htmlMessage) {
  this.name = name;
  this.message = message;
  this.htmlMessage = htmlMessage;
  Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.userException);
  this.toString = function () {
    return name + ' : ' + message;
  }
};
```

While I was trying to create custom exceptions i found this `Error.captureStackTrace` in Node JS document. First i used it like below.

```
Error.captureStackTrace(this, userException);
```

Which `console.error(error)` gave no output.By mistake I changed the line to

```
Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.userException);
```

Which return object the contains properties of `userException` methods. Also `console.error(error.stack);` prints the `stack trace`. I'm so confused how does `this` keyword works in this statement `Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.userException);`. what are `this` keywords of first and second arguments pointed to? is it to the same `Controller` object? But again, why i had to provide `this` as the first  and second argument, in order this to work?

Comment: You should not place constructor functions on prototype objects. They are no methods.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're calling `userException` via `new`, `this` within it is the new object created by the `new` operator. This is different from now you normally call prototype functions and suggests that `userException` probably shouldn't be on `Controller.prototype`.

Your code was failing when you didn't have `this.userException` because it was expecting that there would be an in-scope `userException` identifier, but there wasn't (it's a property of the controller prototype, not a freestanding identifier).

It started working when you added `this.` in front of it because that no longer looks for a freestanding identifier, it looks for a property of `this` with that name. There isn't any, but that's fine, it just ends up passing `undefined` into `captureStackTrace`.

Looking at what I can find for `captureStackTrace`, the second argument is optional and if given is expected to be a function, so presumably it's just ignoring the `undefined` you give it and you could/should be doing  `Error.captureStackTrace(this);` instead.

Related:

- [*What is the 'new' keyword in JavaScript?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646698/what-is-the-new-keyword-in-javascript?rq=1)
- [*How does the "this" keyword work?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Note that subclassing `Error` is *quite difficult* in ES5 and earlier; don't try to roll your own, use something someone's already built for you. The nice folks behind Babel (the JavaScript transpiler you can use to use ES2015 [and beyond] on ES5 JavaScript engines) have done that work for you. You could use ES2015's `class` syntax to extend `Error` and use Babel to transpile. But that might be overkill for whatever you're trying to do.